# What does "get someone's chest opened" mean?

Tags: meaning

I came across this expression in an article:
"My chest opened and has not closed ever since."

Based on the content (He saw the little girl cried), I think it means his heart is broken.

But I couldn't find any explanation. Was my guessing right? And is it a phrase or an idiom, or just an expression from west culture? I mean why an open chest is a metaphor for broken heart? (Quite beyond my understanding)

Thanks so much!

Best,
Shuo

> While I was in El Salvador in June, waiting for my interview, the Trump administration’s policy of separating children from their parents at the border was in full swing. I was staying with my grandfather. One morning I decided to check my email. I hadn’t looked at it in days. Someone had sent a link to a news story: “We have an orchestra here,” were the words a border patrol agent said in a recording released by ProPublica.org. I knew better than to click the link, but I did anyway. Grandpa had already gone to the market and brought back tamales de elote, beans, queso fresco. He never let me go to the market with him. That little girl’s cries and the cries of the other children on the recording were the coldest rain that did not stop. ***My chest opened and has not closed since.***
>   —“[I Have a Green Card Now. But Am I Welcome?](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/11/03/opinion/sunday/immigration-el-salvador-trump-united-states.html)”, *New York Times*, retrieved 8 November 2018.

Comment: You should include a link or a reference to the place where you found this quote.

Comment: It's pretty long. So I added that paragraph.

Comment: Thank you for asking. A Stack Exchange question should be objective and specific enough that it has one clearly “right” answer. The meaning of a text or utterance is generally so subjective that we cannot give a “right” answer. This is why requests for literary criticism, discussion, analysis, and divining the author’s intent are generally off topic. This includes (but is not limited to) literature, lyrics, poetry, and legal documents. See: “[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center](/help/on-topic)”.

Comment: If you have an objective question, such as “What does (word) mean in this context?” or “How does (grammar or punctuation rule) apply in this context?” then please [edit] to add the information our community needs in order to give a correct answer. Detail the effort you have already made to find an answer, solutions you have already rejected, and why. For example, what did you find in peer-reviewed sources, such as a dictionary, thesaurus, or grammar, or other questions on this site? See: “[How much research is needed? – EL&U Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039#5043)”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that you're spot on with your thoughts on the expression. I feel as if it was his way of saying that his heart went out to the little girl with a great deal of sadness, pain and emotion lIke never before! I see his expression, "My chest opened and has not closed ever since. " Meant that his emotions were touched and opened in such a way to where he could not shut out his feelings now, even if he wanted!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just never seen this expression before. So maybe it’s from his country. I was expecting it’s a common use in American English, but it seems it’s not.

Comment: Thank you. I'm from the Eastern US and there are so many expressions and idioms, that I have a hard time deriving the true meaning of most! It's challenging to say the least.